# Как сделать так чтобы при пустом input определённый элемент скрывался?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Написал так: когда начинаешь печатать в input появляется span, но дело в том, что если потом стереть то, что написал, то этот span остаётся, а надо чтобы скрывался. Написал условие внутри функции, но что-то не срабатывает, span вообще не появляется.

```js
$('label.form-group').keyup(function() {
  $(this).children('span:first-child').show();

  if ($('label.form-group input').value === '' || $('label.form-group input').value === this.defaultValue) {
    $('label.form-group>span:first-child').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-group">
    <span>×</span>
    <input class="form-control validate" id="email" type="text" required>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jquery используется `val()` вместо `value`;

`this.defaultValue` → `$(this).defaultValue`;

Ну и я бы все-таки вешал обработчик события на инпут, а не на лейбл, мало ли как там с разметкой потом будет.

```js
$('.form-control').keyup(function() {
  $(this).prev().show();

  if ($(this).val() === '' || $(this).val() === $(this).defaultValue) {
    $(this).prev().hide();
  }
});
```

```css
label.form-group span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-group">
    <span>×</span>
    <input class="form-control validate" id="email" type="text" required>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('label.form-group input').value` будет возвращать `undefined`. В `jQuery` для получения значения нужно использовать метод `val`. Вам видимо нужно что-то подобное, если я правильно понял:

```js
$('label.form-group').keyup(function () {
 $(this).children('span:first-child').show();

 if ($('label.form-group input').val().trim() === '' || $('label.form-group input').val().trim() === this.defaultValue) {
   $('label.form-group>span:first-child').hide();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="form-group">
    <span style="display:none">×</span>
    <input class="form-control validate" id="email" type="text" required>
</label>
```

Для изучения:

1. [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
2. [jQuery.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) - думаю тоже будет полезно

Answer (score 0):

Пример ответа , отслеживаю событие change
javascript:

```
$("#email").on("change", function () {

    var parent  = $(this).parent()[0],
            yourSpan = $(parent).find("span")[0];

    if ($(this).val() == "") {
    $(yourSpan).hide();
  } else {
        $(yourSpan).show();
    }
})
```

И HTML:

```
<label class="form-group">
    <span>×</span>
    <input class="form-control validate" id="email" type="text" required>
</label>
```